# Kiddush Levanah on Friday night

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, kiddush-levanah, leil-shabbat

Why do we avoid making the Bracha of Kiddush Levanah on Friday night and the nights of Yomim Tovim?

Comment: Check Shulchan Aruch 426 which deals with Birkat Halevana.
The reason for doing it Motzei Shabat or Motzei Yom Tov is that you are in good mood and wearing nice clothes.
But there are other customs: 1. Only after 7 days
2. As soon as possible after 3 days without waiting for Motzei Shabat (Hagra).

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question was unclear

Comment: @rony Check the revised version of the question. He is asking why NOT do it on FRIDAY night.

Comment: Who's "we"? How do you know that this "we" has this practice?

Answer (score 13):

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48844&st=&pgnum=168

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48844&st=&pgnum=169

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48844&st=&pgnum=171

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48844&st=&pgnum=173

1 - Although L'Chatchila we do not make Kiddush Levana Friday night and on nights of Yom Tov, if the forecast for after this night is cloudy, or if it is the last night you may do it on those nights.

2 - The reasons given not to make Kiddush Levana on Friday night are as follows.

A: Maharil, MaHara M'Pano, Sefer Agada - Just like there are Techum issues in this world, there are also Techum issues above, and it is inappropiate to greet the Shechina out of the Techum. The Radbaz says that this is a weak reason not to do Kiddush Levana on these nights.

B: MaHara M'Pano - Since Kovod Shabbos and Kedushas Yom Tov are more than greeting the Levana, we do not mix two Simchos.

C: Minhagei Maharil - Birchas HaLevana is like a Techina, which we do not say on Yom Tov.

D: Sdei Chemed - You may come to carry the Siddur into Reshus HaRabim on Shabbos.

E: Rashba - It is a Taam Sod.

Answer (score 1):

also

אורח חיים סימן תכו סעיף ב

שער הציון שם

ועל פי פשוטו יש לומר,
משום דעושין את המצוה בשמחה ורגיל לבא לידי ריקודין,
 וכמו דמשמע אחר כך בהג"ה, וזה איסור בשבת. ואף דריקודין של מצוה התירו וכמו בשמחת תורה, שאני התם דאי אפשר לדחות היום, מה שאין כן הכא דאפשר לעשות המצוה מקודם השבת או לדחות לאחר השבת

Comment: Many people do not fully understand Hebrew on this site - it would be ideal if you would offer a translation, or a synthesis of the key ideas, in English. Many thanks and welcome to MY !

Comment: Once it is expanded and explained it would be better.

Comment: Hi Haim. As hinted above, this is currently an English language site. While Hebrew quotes are a useful addition to a post, it must contain at minimum an English answer such as a summary or translation of the Hebrew text. This answer is not helpful to someone who only speaks English, so it may be deleted. Please [edit] in some English content to improve and save your post

Comment: One might come to do other Melachos on Friday and Yom Tov nights, such as move a flashlight or candle to see the words of the Siddur, etc...